# Dropdown list not appearing in editable table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I want to create an editable table. In which i can change the content of the table cells. Simple input is working fine but, dropdown or select  is not working. Here is a sample what i have done.

```js
$(function() {
    $("td").click(function() {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        console.log(OriginalContent);
        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option >3</option></select>");
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        $(this).children().first().keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = OriginalContent;
                $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                console.log('value' + $(this).val());
            }
        });
        $(this).children().first().blur(function() {
            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.editableTable {
    border:solid 0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center
}
.editableTable td {
    border:solid 1px;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing {
    padding: 0;   
}
select{
  border:0px;
  border-color:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="editableTable">
       
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Problem i'm facing**

- Dropdown or options are not appearing properly and when i click on them twice it took all options and merge them and set to the original value.

**What i need here**

- An editable table with options but options or dropdown should appear only when a cell is clicked.
- After pressing enter, the new value appear in the console and original value remain in it's cell.
- If possible then, dropdown or option should not be appear like a dropdown or options and the right arrow shouldn't be shown.
- After clicking in the cell, the width of the cell shouldn't be change.

Help me find a better way to do this or tell me what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set custom button for **Edit** function in your table. 
In your code when you first click on **td** your click event is fire.
And also when you click on drop-down at that time also **td click** event fire.
because that drop-down options are not appearing properly

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to put any custom button to make them editable. I made them distinguish by making cell editable on double-click then drop-down will appear and remains there till i press enter or tab.